# bash getopts cuts out if the argument is a filename?

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm working on a script with getopts and the command can have arguments in any order, both valid arguments like `-a` and filenames like `stuff.txt`. The problem is, when I run a command like this:

`program.sh -a -b stuff.txt  -c -d`

My code processes arguments `-a` and `-b` okay until it gets to the filename, then it stops processing and doesn't touch arguments `-c` and `-d` afterwards. My code looks a bit like this:

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d" opt; do

case "$opt" in

    a) # do something;;

    b) # do something;;

    /?) echo ERROR
        exit 1;;

esac
done
```

I work on the files outside of the `while` loop and they seem to register just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've indicated that each option requires an argument because of the presence of a colon after each option letter in `":a:b:c:d"` (the first colon affects error processing), the script sees `-b` as the argument to `-a`. When it encounters the filename, it detects that option processing should stop.

You should either supply an argument to `-a` or remove the colons from option letters that don't require arguments.

After making these corrections, your script will see the file name as an argument to `-b` and the variable `$OPTARGS` will contain the filename when `-b` is being processed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have fixed that.  What I need to do is be able to enter something like: program.sh -a 2 -b 4 stuff.txt -c 5 -d   and have getopts() not screw up -c and -d on me because I also need to stick a filename in there at any time, independent of arguments.  That is to say filenames do not depend on being an option to an argument.

Comment: @user1419715: Put arguments that are not option arguments after all the options and their arguments. You can test for non-compliance to that and handle it as an error. If you can't do that, then `getopts` is not suitable for your needs and you'll have to roll your own.